# my batch file only open 1 file even i got more file in my path

Tags: batch-file

can you help me with my code
it only open 1 file in my folder but how? that folder contain 8 file..
can some one help me im new in batch scripting thank you

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Extract date fields - language dependent
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (
        set v1=%%i& set v2=%%j& set v3=%%k
        if "%%i:~0,1%%" gtr "9" (set v1=%%j& set v2=%%k& set v3=%%l)

        for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo.^|date') do (
            set %%m=!v1!& set %%n=!v2!& set %%o=!v3!
    )
)
:: Final set for language independency (English and Portuguese - maybe works for Spanish and French)
set year=%yy%%aa%
set month=%mm%
set day=%dd%
set a=2
set /a c=%dd%+%a%
set var=00%c%
set var=%var:~-2%
:: Testing
echo Year:[%year%] - month:[%month%] - day:[%var%]
start "" EXCEL.exe "\\mwcfs\DC Duty Files\SAP PROCESSING\OSB DOWNLOAD\FOR DOWNLOAD\%year%\%month% December %year%\Day %var%\*.xlsx"
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: (1) It would help people to understand your code if you would add a few more comments (starting with the format of the data that you are expecting from the `date` commands, and what you are trying to do with your `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `m`, `n`, and `o` variables) and explain what the script is trying to do, overall.  (2) On my (en_US) system, `echo.|date` (cute trick, by the way) produces two lines of output: ```The current date is: Thu 12/14/2017``` and ```Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)```.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  By saying `skip=1`, your code ends up parsing the `Enter the new date` line, which is probably not what you intend.  (3) … except it doesn’t seem to be using the information it gets from `echo.|date`, since the `for` statement sets variables `m`, `n`, and `o`, and you immediately overwrite those values with data you already had.  (4) Are you setting variables `yy`, `aa`, `mm`, and `dd` somewhere?  If so, you should explain that.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Or maybe leave out all the date-processing stuff, because (5) When I say ``start "" excel *.xlsx``, I get an error message (from Excel 2013) that `*.xlsx` was not found. Have you tried building the directory path by hand and just testing whether your version of Excel can handle wildcards (like `*`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FOR` command to iterate over all the files in that directory and then use excel to open each one.  I am using the PUSHD command to temporarily change the working directory to where the files are located.  The POPD command forces the working directory back to the previous directory

```
PUSHD "\\mwcfs\DC Duty Files\SAP PROCESSING\OSB DOWNLOAD\FOR DOWNLOAD\%year%\%month% December %year%\Day %var%\"
for %%G in (*.xlsx) do start "" excel.exe "%%~G"
POPD
```

Here is a better way to get the date and time in a YYYYMMDDhhmmss format

```
REM Get date and time in YYYYMMDDhhmmss format
for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
```

This will output 20171214150615.  You can then use the set command and substrings to create individual variables for each date and time segment.